# Intuition and use of CDF when we either have PMF or PDF with us

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

When we speak about Discrete random variables we have PMF. When speaking about Continuous random variable we have PDF. So my question is if we already have PDF or PMF with us then why do we use or calculate CDF, what's the intuition behind CDF

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I disagree. The question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer is that not all random variables are  continuous *or* discrete, and not all continuous random variables *have* density functions.  It is sometimes  convenient, from a theoretical point of view, to have a way of specifying a probability law with a single kind of mathematical object that covers all cases.  It turns out that *all* random variables have cumulative distribution functions, and *all* random variables have characteristic functions, but *not all* random variables have a probability mass function or density function.

Here are some examples.  Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ be a standard normal random variable.  It is a continuous random variable and has well-known density function $f(x)=\exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$.  But the random variable $X=\max(0,Z)$ built out of $Z$ is not a continuous random variable and is not a discrete random variable, and doesn't has a pdf or a pmf.  If you construct a random decimal fraction $Y$ by flipping a fair coin to determine its successive  digits after the decimal point (so the sequence HHTHHTT... gives rise to decimal fraction .1101100) you get a continuous random variable that does not have a density function.

I agree, it is hard for a beginner to keep track of all these different ways of specifying probability laws, and being asked to think about cdfs on top of everything else can seem like an imposition.  From my point of view, the concept of a cdf simplifies everything else: it means that much of the detail about probability mass functions, probability generating functions, and so on, can be put on the back burner: all the relevant info (and *only* the relevant info) is packed into the cdf.

Answer (score 0):

Take the case of continous random variables. A PDF on its own doesn't really tell us much. Take a normal RV with a mean of 0 and standard deviation 1. The PDF has a peak at 0, so that tells us that values of around about 0 are the most likely. It's value at 0 is ~0.4. Does that mean that the probability that the RV turns out to be 0 is 0.4? No, in fact the probability that it turns out to be 0 is actually 0. There is no chance that it will be 0. The PDF can however tell us the likelihood that it will be between 2 numbers, like that it turns out to be between -0.5 and +0.5. To find that probability, we have to integrate it from -0.5 to +0.5. The CDF is much handier. It tells us actual probabilities. The CDF for the same random variable is 0.5 at 0. That tells us that there is a 50/50 chance that the RV turns out to be less than 0. The value of the cdf at 1 is ~0.83. That tells us that the probability that it turns out to be less than 1 is 83%. The CDF is very useful.